# DynamicRelationField not detected

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, dynamic-rest

I am using [dynamic-rest](https://github.com/AltSchool/dynamic-rest). According to the [documentation](https://github.com/AltSchool/dynamic-rest#features), I have this model with a dynamically generated foreign key:

```
class PscSerializer(DynamicModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = PSC
        name = 'psc'
        fields = ('id', 'description', 'created', 'modified', 'pscno', 'productno', 'serviceno', 'luns')

    luns = DynamicRelationField('LunSerializer', many=True)
```

Which produces:

```
Exception Type: AttributeError at /api/v1/pscs/
Exception Value: luns is not a valid field for <class 'pscs.models.PSC'>
```

Sure, `luns` is not a field in the `PSC` model, but a dynamic field. What is going on? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I've never used DREST before, but in the example you point to, both the dynamic relation fields are already defined as relationships on the model.

Comment: @RishiG thanks. That is not the model, but the serializer. I have not shown the model, since it suffices to know that `luns` is not a field, as explained.

Comment: In the example you refer to in the documentation, the `User` model has `location` and `groups` fields, which are the dynamic relation fields in the serializer.  I think it's designed to add functionality to the serializer for fields that already exist on the model.